# Is there a way to adjust R PerformanceAnalytics function VaR with EWMA or GARCH method?

Tags: volatility, r, garch, value-at-risk, performanceanalytics

Is there a way to upgrade R PerformanceAnalytics function VaR with more risk sensitive approaches like EWMA or GARCH? Or is there another R package which can handle the issue?

Comment: Since R is open-source, you can change the code to meet your needs. You can open the source code for a function using the edit function. After that, doing what you're trying to do might require a fair bit of hacking, but I can't imagine it's impossible.

Comment: @jamos125 Agreed. Moreover, we all lose when someone shies from such enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the  parameters are you estimating with  EWMA or GARCH using the  mu (mean), sigma (co/variance) m3 (co/skewness) and m4(co/kurtosis) arguments.

e.g. blahblah = EWMA(my_time_series)

VaR(my_time_series,mu=blahblah)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the EWMA approach have a look at cov.wt() from the stats package. It will give you an EWMA volatility, which you can then, given the normal distribution assumption, easily transform into VaR.